# A boy died in the middle of sex and died and met with a goddess and reincarnated him as a baby in the forest and got adopted by a human woman

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga. The chapter began with a boy and beautiful lady, who is a goddess. She was pitying him for dying in the middle of sex and she reincarnated him as a baby in the forest. He got adopted by a lady and she raised him and he began to see her face and enjoying his childhood.